# Ajax ReadyState 1 in FF only?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I have a script that changes the width of a div depending on the percentage and webpage page returns (A webpage on my site return the percentage of a file in a header and Ajax reads the header)
Here is that script: http://pastebin.com/eGZFQvDK

This works great for Chrome. Internet explorer (at least in older IE) doesn't work at all. It doesn't say any errors but it doesn't change the width either... Firefox is pretty weird actually.... It changes the width properly but it also echos "Progress Bar Error: Ready State is 1" yet it is still changing the width properly. I could remove the error message but that's not really fixing the problem.

This seems to be a problem for lots of people but all the posts I read seem to be just for certain situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the `xhr` and if request is `asynch` then you should use `true` instead. This should work for you.

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET",'/progressbar.php?progress_key='+upload_id, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I tried it with that on and off. It works fine in google chrome with it on, but it won't work at all in FF and never tried it in IE

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I fell asleep after posting this and had school in the morning.

Comment: K I changed the error message from "Progress Bar Error: Response code not 200" to Progress Bar Error: Response code is "+xmlhttp.status and its saying the response code is 0? I checked the headers and its sending a request but there is no response header? This setup works fine in google chrome.